# using cmake to install files to /usr/sbin

Tags: linux, cmake, yum, cpack

I'm having some issues installing a script into `/usr/sbin` from a cmake script. In my `packaging.cmake` I have

```
install(FILES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/kpcmdctrl" DESTINATION /usr/sbin COMPONENT kptester
            PERMISSIONS OWNER_EXECUTE OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ GROUP_EXECUTE GROUP_READ)
```

and in the generated spec file:

```
%files                       
%defattr(-,root,root,-)      
%dir "/opt/mycomp"      
%dir "/opt/mycomp/kptester_prog"
%dir "/opt/mycomp/kptester_prog/bin"
"/opt/mycomp/kptester_prog/bin/kptester"
%dir "/opt/mycomp/kptester_prog/etc"
%dir "/usr/sbin"

%config "/usr/sbin/kpcmdctrl"
```

when I run `yum localinstall kptester-0.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm` I get the following error:

```
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /usr/sbin from install of kptester-0.0.1-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.8-6.el8.x86_64
```

I've tried installing the script in other places such as `/usr/bin` and it works without issue. I've checked the package listing for `filesystem-3.8-6.el8.x86_6` [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/8-stream/centos-baseos-x86_64/filesystem-3.8-6.el8.x86_64.rpm.html) and I can't see any reason for it to complain?

Am I missing something obvious or is `/usr/sbin` a special directory?

Comment: If I understand this right, the problem is not with CMake but with yum.

Comment: Could be yes, I'll add the additional tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my own solution in case anyone else comes across this problem. The problem was that the RPM was trying to own the system folder e.g. `/usr/sbin`. You can see this from the spec file I posted in the question: `%dir "/usr/sbin"`

There is an option in cmake to tell it not do to this:

```
set(CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST_ADDITION "/usr/sbin")
```

or if you have more than one system folder:

```
list(APPEND CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST_ADDITION "/usr/sbin")
```

The new spec file doesn't have the system folder listed as a directory and install works as expected.